# I dont know how to create responsive columns on my website?

Tags: html, css, responsive, mobile-website

I am having hard time to make this grid responsive. I have 2 rows and 3 columns with each having picture and text. Pictures are same size. I want to make it responsive, so when it reaches certain width, the columns reposition under each other and font size changes to smaller font. Thx for help!

#### Picture:

[image]

```css
.domov2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0 50px 0;
  background-color: #D5D7D7;
  min-height: 450px;
}

.domov22 {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 960px;
  min-width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-height: 450px;
}

.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 10%;
  row-gap: 50px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* top right bot left*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 23% 24% 23%;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.slika {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="domov2">
  <section class="domov22">
    <div class="grid-container">

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/computer.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Izdelamo vam vizualno atraktivno, urejeno spletno stran.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/presentation.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Povečajte svojo prodajo in prepoznavnost s privlačno in urejeno spletno stranjo.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/brand.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> SEO optimizacija. Vašo spletno stran optimiziramo tako, da bo dosegala visoke pozicije na “google” iskalniku.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/support.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Zastonj vzdrževanje (posodabljanje vtičnikov in varnostno kopiranje) prve tri mesece po izdelavi spletne strani.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/consulting.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Hitra, prijazna in odzivna podpora uporabnikom.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/discussion.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Nudimo brezplačno prvo svetovanje na daljavo. </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Use `flex` for responsiveness and `mediaqueries` for  responsive `fonts`

Comment: Do what @Manjuboyz says and also add “flex-wrap: wrap” to the main container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made you mobile adaptation at your discretion. In the css you can see the added two media queries `@media`. You can set the resizing numbers to your liking. Also, I removed the `min-width: 960px` rule in `.domov22` because this rule prevented the blocks from being made "rubber". Also, I've replaced your grid-`template-columns: 23% 24% 23%` on `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` Hope it helped. If you have any questions, please contact.

```css
.domov2{
  width:100%;
  padding: 0px 0 50px 0;
  background-color: #D5D7D7;
  min-height:450px;  }

.domov22{
  width:80%;
  max-width:960px;
  /*min-width:960px;*/
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-height:450px;  }

.grid-container {
  position:relative;
  column-gap:10%;
  row-gap:50px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px; /* top right bot left*/
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: 23% 24% 23%;*/
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px ;
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: justify;}

.slika{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width:220px;
  min-width:220px;}

  .center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
    
  @media(max-width: 950px){
   .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      }
  }
  
   @media(max-width: 550px){
   .grid-container {
      grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
      }
  }
```

```html
<section class="domov2">
        <section class="domov22">
            <div class="grid-container">

                <div><div class=slika> <img src="slike/computer.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br>
                Izdelamo vam vizualno atraktivno, urejeno spletno stran.</div>

                <div><div class=slika> <img src="slike/presentation.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br>
                Povečajte svojo prodajo in prepoznavnost s privlačno in urejeno spletno stranjo.</div>

                <div><div class=slika> <img src="slike/brand.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br>
                SEO optimizacija. Vašo spletno stran optimiziramo tako, da bo dosegala visoke pozicije na “google” iskalniku.</div>

                <div><div class=slika> <img src="slike/support.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br>
                Zastonj vzdrževanje (posodabljanje vtičnikov in varnostno kopiranje) prve tri mesece po izdelavi spletne strani.</div>

                <div><div class=slika> <img src="slike/consulting.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br>
                Hitra, prijazna in odzivna podpora uporabnikom.</div>

                <div><div class=slika> <img src="slike/discussion.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br>
                Nudimo brezplačno prvo svetovanje na daljavo. </div>   
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

You can auto size your columns without using `@media` query

This adjusts your columns according to screen size

```css
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

```css
.domov2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0 50px 0;
  background-color: #D5D7D7;
  min-height: 450px;
}

.domov22 {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 960px;
  /*min-width:960px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  min-height: 450px;
}

.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  column-gap: 10%;
  row-gap: 50px;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
  /* top right bot left*/
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: 23% 24% 23%;*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 300px 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.slika {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media(max-width: 950px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media(max-width: 550px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="domov2">
  <section class="domov22">
    <div class="grid-container">

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/computer.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Izdelamo vam vizualno atraktivno, urejeno spletno stran.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/presentation.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Povečajte svojo prodajo in prepoznavnost s privlačno in urejeno spletno stranjo.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/brand.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> SEO optimizacija. Vašo spletno stran optimiziramo tako, da bo dosegala visoke pozicije na “google” iskalniku.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/support.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Zastonj vzdrževanje (posodabljanje vtičnikov in varnostno kopiranje) prve tri mesece po izdelavi spletne strani.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/consulting.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Hitra, prijazna in odzivna podpora uporabnikom.</div>

      <div>
        <div class=slika> <img src="slike/discussion.png" height=140 class="center"></div><br> Nudimo brezplačno prvo svetovanje na daljavo. </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```